# Как вызвать функцию с параметром?

Tags: c++

Использую cocs2d-x
Имеется сцена-селектор уровней `lvlSel`.
Имеется сцена с базовым набором уровня `lvl`.
Имеется функция `loadLevel(int ID)` для отрисовки уровня из файла `lvl_ID`. 
Имеется функция `initScene(int lvlswitch)`, переключающая сцены через replaceScene().
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу вызвать `loadLevel` с нужным параметром после инициализации новой сцены. Если использовать отрисовку внутри инициализации, то не могу передать необходимый параметр для `loadLevel()`.
Как можно вызвать эту функцию после инициализации сцены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно говоря не совсем ясен вопрос, но ведь всегда можно унаследоваться от того, кто реализует эти функции, и изменить структуру и replaceScene() и всех остальных.
Также можно сделать статик класс, или глабальную переменную (на худой конец) которая будет хранить нужный параметр.

Comment: loadLevel кастомная функция с параметром, которая грузит графику конкретного уровня (тот самый параметр) на сцену Level. initScenes тоже кастомная функция. Вызывает конкретную сцену также через параметр.

Comment: Повесь на сцену в ините объект - таймер. Так как это кокос2dx используй  schedule( schedule_selector(Object::tick) ); Так ты можешь вызвать всё что угодно.
Я делаю предположение. На самом, деле наверное я туплю, но я не совсем понимаю ситуацию.

Comment: в заголовочном файле описывается класс сцены, её инициализатор Level::init() и доп функции, если необходимо. В моём случает - подгрузка графики и подгрузка UI. UI у всех уровней одинаковое, так что параметры ему не нужны и она спокойно вызывается из инициализатора сцены. А вот сами уровни различаются и внутри инициализатора его вызвать не получается без передачи параметра. В .cpp сначала описывается базовая функция scene(), а потом уже запускается инициализатор. replaceScene использует именно scene() для смены сцены, а уже та вызывает инициализатор.

Comment: но как мне передать вызываемой функции параметр? я могу спокойно написать её туда без таймера. Она сработает, только все уровни у меня будут одинаковые, т.к. ID карты не меняется

Comment: void CCDirector::replaceScene(CCScene *pScene)
{
 CCAssert(pScene != NULL, "the scene should not be null");

 unsigned int index = m_pobScenesStack->count();

 m_bSendCleanupToScene = true;
 m_pobScenesStack->replaceObjectAtIndex(index - 1, pScene);

 m_pNextScene = pScene;
}

Эта функция должна передать параметр?

Создайте Класс надстройку над директором, и вызывайте replaceScene(int myID), которая вызывает loadLevel(int ID) после инициализации сцены.

Comment: глобальная переменная затащила